# SWRevealViewController how to fix popoViewController to work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue, pushviewcontroller

When i open the app, rearView and frontView works great.
In frontView, i touch on a button and i can: 
`[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];`
normally and then, in **detailViewController**: 
`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`
normally and beautiful.

But, when, in rearView, i touch a button to `setFrontViewController` or `pushFrontViewController`  to update data in **mainViewController** ( frontView ), then i loose:
`[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];`
does not work **AND**
`[self.revealViewController pushFrontViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];`
**NOT** do the animation. Really sad!!!
But, the main problem, using `pushFrontViewController` to open **detailViewController**. i cant `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`, **OR** `[self.revealViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`
**OR** anything to go back works...

Simple this doenst work when update the FrontView...

Even with segue...

Thanks for any idea

Comment: I've been using the SWRevealViewController and have it working it my app I'm developing for a similar scenario that you have mentioned, and it does work for me. So, could be something with the way your navigation is setup perhaps? Perhaps publish code around what happens when you click a button in the rearView before you set the FrontVC?

Comment: @GurtejSingh can i send my project to you see? I have storyboard and code, many things to paste here. If i could send of course. Thanks

Comment: Sure buddy, upload it somewhere and share the link. I'll take a look at it when I get some time. Thanks.

Comment: @GurtejSingh sorry for delay, fallow the link http://www.rd3digital.com.br/tempFiles/Patrini.zip , i put `presentViewController` to solve temporally for the client. But wee want a fancy and elegant and default transition! rsrsr Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks Jack. Please give me some time to have a look at it and I'll revert back with hopefully a fix.

Comment: @GurtejSingh no problem! i need more 5 min to complete UPLOAD this files, kinda big hehehe Thanks again for your time!

Comment: Hey Jack, just tried to download your files but got a 404 instead. Am I too late to download them? Sorry I was out. Please let me know.

Comment: Sorry, miss link it is Patriani.zip i miss an a

Comment: Nice!!! When you open, is MenuViewController and ViewController(iphone) or CollectionViewController(ipad)... in menu, the third uiswitch that change de front with data

Comment: Just finished downloading and opened the project. Got one error for now, first to get the project to run.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85472/discussion-between-gurtej-singh-and-jack-loverde).

Comment: Hey Jack, I was able to resolve your issues. Let me know when you will be online and then we can discuss. Thanks

Comment: Iam on chat, call me there when you get online, thanks

Comment: I am online now, please see if you can join the same chat! Thanks.

Comment: Iam online, sorry for delay

Comment: I'm online from my mobile can you see me?

Comment: Hey, did you get a chance to see my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after taking a look at your code, I found that the issue was with connecting the right segue from your collection cell, or your table view cell to the `ProductDetailViewController`.

The issue was not with the `SWRevealViewController`, and you should only use the `setFrontViewController` method only when you are accessing something in your menu and are moving to a new page altogether. Navigation between the pages should be managed via segues only.

Also, another issue I found is when you are switching on/off the switches in your `MenuViewController` class, since you are resetting the `frontViewController` with new data, you should embed it in a Navigation Controller first otherwise the segues won't work again.

Hope this clarifies and solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help and availability!!! For who will read this, i you delete the project because it is too large to stay online.